# C++ Differences in the unoptimized assembly generated based on number of members

Tags: c++, xcode, assembly

I am wondering why, for example, the assembly generated when passing an object with 3 int members appears to contain far more redundant copying than when passing an object with 4 int members. I am compiling on OS X and get roughly the same result using both Eclipse and Xcode.

With 3 members:

```
struct X{
    int a,b,c;
    X(int i) : a{i}, b{i+1}, c{i+2} {}
};

int f(X p1, X p2){
    int res = p1.b + p2.c + 22;
    return res;
}

int main() {
    int x = f(5,10);
    return 0;
}
```

The following assembly is produced in Xcode:

```
test`main:
    0x100000ed0 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
    0x100000ed1 <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x100000ed4 <+4>:   subq   $0x50, %rsp
    0x100000ed8 <+8>:   leaq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdi
    0x100000edc <+12>:  movl   $0x5, %esi
    0x100000ee1 <+17>:  movl   $0x0, -0x4(%rbp)
->  0x100000ee8 <+24>:  callq  0x100000f40               ; X::X at main.cpp:14
    0x100000eed <+29>:  leaq   -0x28(%rbp), %rdi
    0x100000ef1 <+33>:  movl   $0xa, %esi
    0x100000ef6 <+38>:  callq  0x100000f40               ; X::X at    main.cpp:14
    0x100000efb <+43>:  movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdi
    0x100000eff <+47>:  movq   %rdi, -0x38(%rbp)
    0x100000f03 <+51>:  movl   -0x10(%rbp), %esi
    0x100000f06 <+54>:  movl   %esi, -0x30(%rbp)
    0x100000f09 <+57>:  movq   -0x38(%rbp), %rdi
    0x100000f0d <+61>:  movl   -0x30(%rbp), %esi
    0x100000f10 <+64>:  movq   -0x28(%rbp), %rax
    0x100000f14 <+68>:  movq   %rax, -0x48(%rbp)
    0x100000f18 <+72>:  movl   -0x20(%rbp), %ecx
    0x100000f1b <+75>:  movl   %ecx, -0x40(%rbp)
    0x100000f1e <+78>:  movq   -0x48(%rbp), %rdx
    0x100000f22 <+82>:  movl   -0x40(%rbp), %ecx
    0x100000f25 <+85>:  callq  0x100000e80               ; f(X, X) at     main.cpp:17
    0x100000f2a <+90>:  xorl   %ecx, %ecx
    0x100000f2c <+92>:  movl   %eax, -0x8(%rbp)
    0x100000f2f <+95>:  movl   %ecx, %eax
    0x100000f31 <+97>:  addq   $0x50, %rsp
    0x100000f35 <+101>: popq   %rbp
    0x100000f36 <+102>: retq
```

The two objects are constructed and then copied to another location before being placed in registers for passing to f(). When a fourth int member is added to X, the objects are constructed and then placed directly in the registers. This seems more logical. Just wondering what would account for the difference.

Then with four members:

```
struct X{
    int a,b,c,d;
    X(int i) : a{i}, b{i+1}, c{i+2}, d{i+3} {}
};

int f(X p1, X p2){
    int res = p1.b + p2.c + 22;
    return res;
}

int main() {
    int x = f(5,10);
    return 0;
}
```

The assembly looks like this:

```
test`main:
    0x100000ee0 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x100000ee1 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x100000ee4 <+4>:  subq   $0x30, %rsp
    0x100000ee8 <+8>:  leaq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdi
    0x100000eec <+12>: movl   $0x5, %esi
    0x100000ef1 <+17>: movl   $0x0, -0x4(%rbp)
->  0x100000ef8 <+24>: callq  0x100000f30               ; X::X at main.cpp:14
    0x100000efd <+29>: leaq   -0x28(%rbp), %rdi
    0x100000f01 <+33>: movl   $0xa, %esi
    0x100000f06 <+38>: callq  0x100000f30               ; X::X at main.cpp:14
    0x100000f0b <+43>: movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdi
    0x100000f0f <+47>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi
    0x100000f13 <+51>: movq   -0x28(%rbp), %rdx
    0x100000f17 <+55>: movq   -0x20(%rbp), %rcx
    0x100000f1b <+59>: callq  0x100000eb0               ; f(X, X) at main.cpp:17
    0x100000f20 <+64>: xorl   %r8d, %r8d
    0x100000f23 <+67>: movl   %eax, -0x8(%rbp)
    0x100000f26 <+70>: movl   %r8d, %eax
    0x100000f29 <+73>: addq   $0x30, %rsp
    0x100000f2d <+77>: popq   %rbp
    0x100000f2e <+78>: retq
```

Thanks.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think you have read the title. If you did you should have noticed it says **unoptimized**  :)

Comment: Can you post the asm for the 4 int code as well? I'm not familiar enough with the internals of the Xcode compiler but it's possible it might have something to do with padding (i.e. `sizeof(int)*4` can fit 'nicely' in the registers vs. `sizeof(int)*3` which needs some extra work) ..?

Comment: I it is unoptimized but I would have thought the behaviour in each case would be fairly similar.

Comment: Unoptimized means "don't care", so the compiler doesn't. Some things just happen and will be fixed by the optimizer later.

Comment: If the compiler was being as "logical" as it could be it wouldn't generate any code at all, as your code has no externally visible effect. My guess is that you crossed a threshold between different copying strategies for the struct, eg. from a member-wise copy to using `memcpy`, and the difference allowed the compiler to see one of the copies wasn't necessary. But who knows, unoptimized code is dumb code by design. It just needs to be correct, it doesn't need to make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

As comments have pointed out, unoptimized code is just that; not optimized. That doesn't mean the compiler won't do *any* optimizations where it makes sense to do so, it just won't do any additional optimizations.

In your code (assuming you're building for an `x86_64`), `sizeof(X)` where `X` has 3 `int` members would be `sizeof(int)*3`, which is 3 * 32-bits (or 1*64-bit + 1*32-bit), where as `sizeof(X)` with 4 `int` members would be `sizeof(int)*4`, which is 4 * 32-bits (or 2*64-bit).

Since the 4 member `X` struct can fit nicely on 2 quad word boundaries, the compiler didn't need to preform any  'optimizations' and can thus do what it did:

```
; movq is a 64-bit instruction
0x100000f0b <+43>: movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdi ; X.a
0x100000f0f <+47>: movq   -0x10(%rbp), %rsi ; X.b
0x100000f13 <+51>: movq   -0x28(%rbp), %rdx ; X.c
0x100000f17 <+55>: movq   -0x20(%rbp), %rcx ; X.d
```

But since the 3 member `X` struct can only fit nicely on 1 quad word boundary (with the remainder sitting on a double word), the compiler had to do some extra work to reference the proper locations of the struct within the registers and thus the output:

```
; movl is a 32-bit instruction
0x100000efb <+43>:  movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdi
0x100000eff <+47>:  movq   %rdi, -0x38(%rbp)
0x100000f03 <+51>:  movl   -0x10(%rbp), %esi ; 32-bit instruction
0x100000f06 <+54>:  movl   %esi, -0x30(%rbp)
0x100000f09 <+57>:  movq   -0x38(%rbp), %rdi
0x100000f0d <+61>:  movl   -0x30(%rbp), %esi
0x100000f10 <+64>:  movq   -0x28(%rbp), %rax
0x100000f14 <+68>:  movq   %rax, -0x48(%rbp)
0x100000f18 <+72>:  movl   -0x20(%rbp), %ecx
0x100000f1b <+75>:  movl   %ecx, -0x40(%rbp)
0x100000f1e <+78>:  movq   -0x48(%rbp), %rdx
0x100000f22 <+82>:  movl   -0x40(%rbp), %ecx
```

Both cases are unoptimized since nothing extra was done to either sets of code; the 4 member struct might appear optimized, but it was not, and chances are that even with optimizations turn on, the assembly for that would probably be the same.

If you enabled optimizations on this code there's a good chance the compiler would have added an extra hidden `int` member in the 3 member `X` so as to properly pad it to fit on the boundaries.

You might also see similarly small asm output if you changed the last type in the 3 member struct to a `long`, example:

```
struct X {
    int a, b; // assuming sizeof(int) === 4
    long c;   // assuming sizeof(long) == 8
};
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks, that's made things a bit clearer. But `struct A{long a; int b;};` produces the concise asm output that I would have expected from the struct with 3 `int` members. I guess I was expecting that all differences in output would be directly attributable to C++ language rules (even if superfluous).